# Module not found error in main.ts file only in ng build --prod

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-routing, angular2-template

Angular2 the application was working fine locally when taking ng build --prod getting a below error. i dont know why this error occur which line in main.ts have a problem.
[image]
Here is the main.ts file.

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';


if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

here is the route:

```
import { NgModule /* ModuleWithProviders */ } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, /* PreloadAllModules */ } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductComponent } from './products/dashboardPerformance/basic/basic.component';
import { OrderComponent } from './products/dashboardPerformance/advanced/advanced.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [

    {path:'Product',component:ProductComponent},
    {path:'order',component:OrderComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { /* preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules */ })
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRouting {
}
```

Angular version:

```
   "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.3",
      "ts-node": "3.0.2",
        "tslint": "^5.1.0",
        "typescript": "2.2.2"

},
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "4.0.3",
```

angular cli version
[image]

Comment: Do you lazy load a module? If you do, show us your routes. Also, your code was working in dev mode because the AOT compilation is disabled by default in dev.

Comment: Do you use latest version of CLI and Angular? If not, try to update first: https://update.angular.io/

Comment: there are lots of features using in this angular2,like third party components, if i updates angular , features gets affected. we will upgrade soon. for time being i update cli alone which will work?i need alternative solution instead of upgrade.